# jetson-python only size-1 arrays can be converted to python scalars

Tags: python, opencv, nvidia-jetson

I'm working on a people-flow-analysis-project at NVIDIA.
[Link](https://github.com/Ryoyo-NV/People-Flow-Analysis-System)

When running Python I get the error "Only arrays of size 1 can be converted to Python scalars".

```
import sys
import os
sys.path.append('../')
import time
import math
import gi
gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0')
from gi.repository import GObject, Gst
import cv2
import numpy as np
from common.is_aarch_64 import is_aarch64
from common.bus_call import bus_call
import camera_calibration as cc
import dwell_time_checker as dt
import tracker_sort as t_sort
import pyds
import constant
class Tracker(cc.Calibration):
#class Tracker(cc.Calibration):

    __func_name = "Tracker"
    __tracker = None
    __display = None

    __fps_streams = {}
    __frame_number = 0
    __saved_count = {}
    __frame_image = None
    __black = None
    __img = None
    __output_img = None
    __pipeline = None
    __id_loc_buffer = []            # Holds raw location and id
    __old_id_loc_buffer = []        # Holds previous location and id for filtering
    __id_grid_loc_buffer = []       # Buffer for dwell time. It holds grid location and id
    __cntr = 0

    __reset_alert_flag = False      # When mouse left-button is double clicked,
                                    # this flag will turn on
    __reset_alert_coor = None       # When mouse left-button is double clicked,
                                    # x and y are saved here as coordinates

    __old_epoch = 0                 # Old epoch to check timing per second

    __track_bounding_boxes = []

    __dwell_time_checker = None      # Holds the instance of class DwellTimeChecker
    __message_manager = None         # Holds the instance of class MessageManager
    __obj_confidence = []            # Holds detected object confidence per frame
    __names = []                     # Holds list of name per frame
    __t_sort = None                  # Holds the instance of class TrackerSort

    # define image variables for display
    __pts1 = None                    # points 1, hold mouse-clicked points
    __pts2 = None                    # points 2, hold points with from variable aspect ratio
    __corner_pts = None              # corner points coordinate
    __corner_point_index = 0         # corner points index
    __cx = 0                         # centroid x data
    __cy = 0                         # centroid y data
    __cx_2d = 0                      # 2d x data
    __cy_2d = 0                      # 2d y data
    __calibrated_flag = False        # flag to know if calibration process is already executed

    __image_flag = []                # When image need to be saved

    __pgie_classes_str = ["Person", "Bag", "Face"]
    __flag = constant.TRK_STATE_NONE # Tracking state initial value

    def __init__(self, message_manager):
        if self.__tracker is None:
            self.__tracker = super().__init__()

            # Set user configuration class instance
            config = message_manager.getUserConfig()

            self.__conf_ar_width = config.get_ar_width()     # Aspect ratio width from user config
            self.__conf_ar_height = config.get_ar_height()   # Aspect ratio height from user config
            self.__conf_ar = config.get_aspect_ratio()       # Aspect ratio from user config
            self.__conf_px_per_ft = config.get_px_per_ft()   # Pixel per feet from user config
            self.__conf_cam_mode = config.get_cam_mode()     # Camera mode from user config

            self.__frame_image = np.zeros((constant.MUXER_OUTPUT_HEIGHT, \
                constant.TILED_OUTPUT_WIDTH, 3), np.uint8)
            self.__black = np.zeros((self.__conf_ar_height, self.__conf_ar_width, 3), np.uint8)
            self.__img = np.zeros((self.__conf_ar_height, self.__conf_ar_width, 3), np.uint8)
            self.__output_img = np.zeros((self.__conf_ar_height, self.__conf_ar_width, 3), np.uint8)
            #self.__display = display
            cc.Calibration.__init__(self)
            self.__dwell_time_checker = dt.DwellTimeChecker(message_manager)
            self.__message_manager = message_manager
            # define points 2
            self.__pts2 = np.float32([[0, 0], \
                [self.__conf_ar[1], 0], \
                [0, self.__conf_ar[0]], \
                [self.__conf_ar[1], \
                self.__conf_ar[0]]])

            # corner points coordinate
            self.__corner_pts = [(0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0)]

            # get instance of the tracker sort class
            self.__t_sort = t_sort.TrackerSort()

        return self.__tracker

    def run(self):
        print(self.__func_name)

    # tiler_sink_pad_buffer_probe  will extract metadata received on tiler src pad
    # and update params for drawing rectangle, object information etc.
    def __tiler_sink_pad_buffer_probe(self, pad, info, u_data):
        frame_number = 0
        num_rects = 0
        obj_counter = {
            constant.PGIE_CLASS_ID_PERSON:0,
            constant.PGIE_CLASS_ID_BAG:0,
            constant.PGIE_CLASS_ID_FACE:0
            }
        gst_buffer = info.get_buffer()
        if not gst_buffer:
            print("Unable to get GstBuffer ")
            return

        image_save_time = False     # Timing to save image

        # Retrieve batch metadata from the gst_buffer
        # Note that pyds.gst_buffer_get_nvds_batch_meta() expects the
        # C address of gst_buffer as input, which is obtained with hash(gst_buffer)
        batch_meta = pyds.gst_buffer_get_nvds_batch_meta(hash(gst_buffer))

        l_frame = batch_meta.frame_meta_list
        self.black = np.zeros((self.__conf_ar_height, self.__conf_ar_width, 3), np.uint8)
        self.black = self.draw_grid(self.black, self.__conf_px_per_ft)
        while l_frame is not None:
            try:
                # Note that l_frame.data needs a cast to pyds.NvDsFrameMeta
                # The casting is done by pyds.NvDsFrameMeta.cast()
                # The casting also keeps ownership of the underlying memory
                # in the C code, so the Python garbage collector will leave
                # it alone.
                frame_meta = pyds.NvDsFrameMeta.cast(l_frame.data)
            except StopIteration:
                break
            #global frame counter
            self.__cntr += 1
            # clear ID and location buffer for new frame
            self.__id_loc_buffer = []
            l_obj = frame_meta.obj_meta_list
            num_rects = frame_meta.num_obj_meta
            is_first_obj = True
            save_image = False
            while l_obj is not None:
                try:
                    # Casting l_obj.data to pyds.NvDsObjectMeta
                    obj_meta = pyds.NvDsObjectMeta.cast(l_obj.data)
                except StopIteration:
                    break
                obj_counter[obj_meta.class_id] += 1
                # Periodically check for objects with borderline confidence value that may be false
                # positive detections. If such detections are found, annoate the frame with bboxes
                # and confidence value. Save the annotated frame to file.
                if is_first_obj:
                    is_first_obj = False
                    # Getting Image data using nvbufsurface
                    # the input should be address of buffer and batch_id
                    n_frame = pyds.get_nvds_buf_surface(hash(gst_buffer), frame_meta.batch_id)
                    #convert python array into numy array format.
                    self.__frame_image = np.array(n_frame, copy=True, order='C')
                    #covert the array into cv2 default color format
                    self.__frame_image = cv2.cvtColor(self.__frame_image, cv2.COLOR_RGBA2BGRA)
                    self.__img = cv2.cvtColor(self.__frame_image, cv2.COLOR_BGRA2BGR)
                save_image = True
                if obj_meta.class_id == constant.PGIE_CLASS_ID_PERSON:
                    # Update tracker sort
                    self.__t_sort.update(obj_meta)
                try:
                    l_obj = l_obj.next
                except StopIteration:
                    break

            # Write connection status
            self.__check_connection_status()

            if self.__calibrated_flag:
                self.__img = self.draw_grid_in_cam(int(self.__img), int(self.__conf_px_per_ft))
```

I'm not familiar with Python.

I found out through a search that 'numpy' and 'math' cannot be used together. Replaced 'math' with 'np' instead of 'numpy'. But I got the same error. What should I fix?

```
error phrase :
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/home/isjetson/People-Flow-Analysis-System/scripts/tracker.py", line 209, in __tiler_sink_pad_buffer_probe

    self.__img = self.draw_grid_in_cam(int(self.__img), int(self.__conf_px_per_ft))

TypeError: only szie-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

```
import sys
import os
sys.path.append('../')
import time

import gi
gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0')
from gi.repository import GObject, Gst
import cv2
import numpy as np
from common.is_aarch_64 import is_aarch64
from common.bus_call import bus_call
import camera_calibration as cc
import dwell_time_checker as dt
import tracker_sort as t_sort
import pyds
import constant
class Tracker(cc.Calibration):
#class Tracker(cc.Calibration):

    __func_name = "Tracker"
    __tracker = None
    __display = None

    __fps_streams = {}
    __frame_number = 0
    __saved_count = {}
    __frame_image = None
    __black = None
    __img = None
    __output_img = None
    __pipeline = None
    __id_loc_buffer = []            # Holds raw location and id
    __old_id_loc_buffer = []        # Holds previous location and id for filtering
    __id_grid_loc_buffer = []       # Buffer for dwell time. It holds grid location and id
    __cntr = 0

    __reset_alert_flag = False      # When mouse left-button is double clicked,
                                    # this flag will turn on
    __reset_alert_coor = None       # When mouse left-button is double clicked,
                                    # x and y are saved here as coordinates

    __old_epoch = 0                 # Old epoch to check timing per second

    __track_bounding_boxes = []

    __dwell_time_checker = None      # Holds the instance of class DwellTimeChecker
    __message_manager = None         # Holds the instance of class MessageManager
    __obj_confidence = []            # Holds detected object confidence per frame
    __names = []                     # Holds list of name per frame
    __t_sort = None                  # Holds the instance of class TrackerSort

    # define image variables for display
    __pts1 = None                    # points 1, hold mouse-clicked points
    __pts2 = None                    # points 2, hold points with from variable aspect ratio
    __corner_pts = None              # corner points coordinate
    __corner_point_index = 0         # corner points index
    __cx = 0                         # centroid x data
    __cy = 0                         # centroid y data
    __cx_2d = 0                      # 2d x data
    __cy_2d = 0                      # 2d y data
    __calibrated_flag = False        # flag to know if calibration process is already executed

    __image_flag = []                # When image need to be saved

    __pgie_classes_str = ["Person", "Bag", "Face"]
    __flag = constant.TRK_STATE_NONE # Tracking state initial value

    def __init__(self, message_manager):
        if self.__tracker is None:
            self.__tracker = super().__init__()

            # Set user configuration class instance
            config = message_manager.getUserConfig()

            self.__conf_ar_width = config.get_ar_width()     # Aspect ratio width from user config
            self.__conf_ar_height = config.get_ar_height()   # Aspect ratio height from user config
            self.__conf_ar = config.get_aspect_ratio()       # Aspect ratio from user config
            self.__conf_px_per_ft = config.get_px_per_ft()   # Pixel per feet from user config
            self.__conf_cam_mode = config.get_cam_mode()     # Camera mode from user config

            self.__frame_image = np.zeros((constant.MUXER_OUTPUT_HEIGHT, \
                constant.TILED_OUTPUT_WIDTH, 3), np.uint8)
            self.__black = np.zeros((self.__conf_ar_height, self.__conf_ar_width, 3), np.uint8)
            self.__img = np.zeros((self.__conf_ar_height, self.__conf_ar_width, 3), np.uint8)
            self.__output_img = np.zeros((self.__conf_ar_height, self.__conf_ar_width, 3), np.uint8)
            #self.__display = display
            cc.Calibration.__init__(self)
            self.__dwell_time_checker = dt.DwellTimeChecker(message_manager)
            self.__message_manager = message_manager
            # define points 2
            self.__pts2 = np.float32([[0, 0], \
                [self.__conf_ar[1], 0], \
                [0, self.__conf_ar[0]], \
                [self.__conf_ar[1], \
                self.__conf_ar[0]]])

            # corner points coordinate
            self.__corner_pts = [(0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0)]

            # get instance of the tracker sort class
            self.__t_sort = t_sort.TrackerSort()

        return self.__tracker

    def run(self):
        print(self.__func_name)

    # tiler_sink_pad_buffer_probe  will extract metadata received on tiler src pad
    # and update params for drawing rectangle, object information etc.
    def __tiler_sink_pad_buffer_probe(self, pad, info, u_data):
        frame_number = 0
        num_rects = 0
        obj_counter = {
            constant.PGIE_CLASS_ID_PERSON:0,
            constant.PGIE_CLASS_ID_BAG:0,
            constant.PGIE_CLASS_ID_FACE:0
            }
        gst_buffer = info.get_buffer()
        if not gst_buffer:
            print("Unable to get GstBuffer ")
            return

        image_save_time = False     # Timing to save image

        # Retrieve batch metadata from the gst_buffer
        # Note that pyds.gst_buffer_get_nvds_batch_meta() expects the
        # C address of gst_buffer as input, which is obtained with hash(gst_buffer)
        batch_meta = pyds.gst_buffer_get_nvds_batch_meta(hash(gst_buffer))

        l_frame = batch_meta.frame_meta_list
        self.black = np.zeros((self.__conf_ar_height, self.__conf_ar_width, 3), np.uint8)
        self.black = self.draw_grid(self.black, self.__conf_px_per_ft)
        while l_frame is not None:
            try:
                # Note that l_frame.data needs a cast to pyds.NvDsFrameMeta
                # The casting is done by pyds.NvDsFrameMeta.cast()
                # The casting also keeps ownership of the underlying memory
                # in the C code, so the Python garbage collector will leave
                # it alone.
                frame_meta = pyds.NvDsFrameMeta.cast(l_frame.data)
            except StopIteration:
                break
            #global frame counter
            self.__cntr += 1
            # clear ID and location buffer for new frame
            self.__id_loc_buffer = []
            l_obj = frame_meta.obj_meta_list
            num_rects = frame_meta.num_obj_meta
            is_first_obj = True
            save_image = False
            while l_obj is not None:
                try:
                    # Casting l_obj.data to pyds.NvDsObjectMeta
                    obj_meta = pyds.NvDsObjectMeta.cast(l_obj.data)
                except StopIteration:
                    break
                obj_counter[obj_meta.class_id] += 1
                # Periodically check for objects with borderline confidence value that may be false
                # positive detections. If such detections are found, annoate the frame with bboxes
                # and confidence value. Save the annotated frame to file.
                if is_first_obj:
                    is_first_obj = False
                    # Getting Image data using nvbufsurface
                    # the input should be address of buffer and batch_id
                    n_frame = pyds.get_nvds_buf_surface(hash(gst_buffer), frame_meta.batch_id)
                    #convert python array into numy array format.
                    self.__frame_image = np.array(n_frame, copy=True, order='C')
                    #covert the array into cv2 default color format
                    self.__frame_image = cv2.cvtColor(self.__frame_image, cv2.COLOR_RGBA2BGRA)
                    self.__img = cv2.cvtColor(self.__frame_image, cv2.COLOR_BGRA2BGR)
                save_image = True
                if obj_meta.class_id == constant.PGIE_CLASS_ID_PERSON:
                    # Update tracker sort
                    self.__t_sort.update(obj_meta)
                try:
                    l_obj = l_obj.next
                except StopIteration:
                    break

            # Write connection status
            self.__check_connection_status()

            if self.__calibrated_flag:
                self.__img = self.draw_grid_in_cam(int(self.__img), int(self.__conf_px_per_ft))

            # Get tracked bounding boxes with corresponding track id
            track_bbs_ids = self.__t_sort.get_tracked_list()
```

Comment: Why are you trying to convert `self.__img`? it seems that `self.draw_grid_in_cam` will take an image as argument... Try with `self.__img = self.draw_grid_in_cam(self.__img, int(self.__conf_px_per_ft))`

Comment: [mre] required.